# How to prove that there are infinitely many irreducibles in $F_q[T]$

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Can any one give a hint to prove that, there are infinitely many irreducibles in $F_q[T]$, function field.

Comment: If you are asking about polynomials in one variable $T$ over the field $F_q$ with $q$ distinct elements, counting the irreducibles by degree is a topic that has been brought up here many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Try adopting Euclid’s proof that there are infinitely many prime numbers. Remember that the common definition of “prime” for the integers is really the definition of “irreducible” in the context of number theory!